# When can calls to a callable() still fail?

Tags: python

The [documentation for `callable()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#callable) in Python 3.6 (and [for Python 2.7](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#callable)) says in part:

> If this returns true, it is still possible that a call fails, but if it is false, calling object will never succeed.

What does it mean to "fail" in this case? Just "standard" function call failures like mismatched arguments, or a raised exception? If something else is meant, what?

In short, in what cases can `callable(obj)` return true but calling `obj()` fail?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, it's trivially true that *any* function call can fail. Maybe you mutated the object between checking `callable` and calling it. Or maybe the object *is* callable, but you passed it invalid arguments, or it raised an exception during operation, or the user just hit ^C, …

But that's not what the docs are warnings about. They're telling you that you can get a `TypeError: <something> is not callable` from doing `func()` even if `callable(func)` returned `True`.

While this isn't exactly documented (maybe to allow other implementations to optimize things?), `callable` is essentially implemented as:

```
def callable(object):
    return hasattr(object, '__call__')
```

And this is at least implied, if not directly stated:

> Note that classes are callable (calling a class returns a new instance); instances are callable if their class has a `__call__()` method.

The key is that really *everything* is an instance. (Classes are instances of their metaclass, which always has a `__call__` method.)

---

So, it's very easy to create something that breaks the test. One way is to just give it a non-callable `__call__`:

```
>>> class C:
...     __call__ = 0
>>> c = C()
>>> callable(c)
True
>>> c()
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

---

Also, notice that claiming that false negatives are impossible ("if it is false, calling object will never succeed") implies that special method lookup on the `__call__` method must use the same mechanism as `callable` (or a strictly weaker one). So, for example, if a Python implementation chooses not to ignore metaclass `__getattribute__` lookup or instance `__dict__` lookup for `__call__`, its `callable` must do the same. And you can see this (at least in CPython 3.7):

```
>>> class D:
...     pass
>>> d = D()
>>> d.__call__ = 0
>>> callable(d)
False
>>> d()
TypeError: 'D' object is not callable
```

(Testing the other special method lookup possibilities is left as an exercise for the reader, meaning I'm too lazy to write them all and happy enough guessing they'll all go the same way…)

---

In CPython, [`callable`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Python/bltinmodule.c#L479) actually just calls the C API method [`PyCallable_Check`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/object.html#c.PyCallable_Check). And [that function](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/object.c#L1408) just checks that the object's type has a `tp_call` slot. For types implemented in Python, that will be true iff `__call__` was defined directly on the class or a base class.